# Binding JBoss AS 7 to all interfaces

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss7.x

I'm running JBoss AS7 in a standalone mode using ./standalone.sh. This binds JBOSS to only localhost. Is there a way to bind it to all the hosts, I mean 0.0.0.0.

The older versions had the -b option to pass 0.0.0.0, I can't find any options to use over here.

Comment: Can you try editing standalone.xml and setting inet-address to 0.0.0.0?  See http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MultipleInstancesOfJBossAS7OnTheSameMachine .

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Edit **standalone/configuration/standalone.xml** and insert the tag **any-address** instead of **inet-address** bound to 127.0.0.1 - Example:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

In the public interface, I've changed the original **inet-address** with **any-address**. After restarting, you'll be able to browse JBoss port 8080 over the network.

Answer (score 18):

Thanks for the tip above,
FYI I discover that using `<any-address/>` might lead to

```
10:31:22,605 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService] (MSC service thread 1-2) Connector.start: LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "jboss.web";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family not supported
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1058)
```

cf. http://community.jboss.org/thread/168789?tstart=120

You might workaround it by replacing it by `<any-ipv4-address/>`

that gives you :

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Comment: +1 what ever the reason for this is. My Jboss instance did work with `<any-address />` as long as it was started manually by executing `standalone.xml`. Only when I configured it to run as a windows service this problem came up and was solved by changing it to `<any-ipv4-address/>`

Comment: Hi I am new to JBoss 7.1.1  can you also explain the purpose of "interface name="management" ...inet-address value="127.0.0.1"  "

Answer (score 13):

We just added support for `-b` in 7.0.2.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do the following:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="0.0.0.0"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

or if you want to bind to a particular address, replace 0.0.0.0 with the ip.

Comment: <inet-address value="0.0.0.0"/>  work better that <any-address/> because you can connect using "localhost" too.
Using WildFly 10.1